# One-liner and how to get results as one-line too

Tags: batch-file

This works fine:

```
@echo off
echo copying & copy /y c:\!chkout\test.bat c:\!chkout\file2.bat
```

and the results are (note: two lines):

```
copying
         1 file(s) copied.
```

would actually like to get to for the results (note: the single line):

```
copying         1 file(s) copied.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SET /P` command with NUL redirection to get the required output.

```
@echo off
set /p ".=copying    "<nul & copy /y c:\!chkout\test.bat c:\!chkout\file2.bat
```

Comment: Works great.  Using a system that shows only the last command processed.